# How to ensure HH:MM:SS time format for a string in Pandas columns

Tags: pandas, time, format

| Name | Gun_time | Net_time | Pace |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 8:48:00 | 28:47:00 | 4:38:00 |
| George | 9:11:00 | 29:10:00 | 14:42:00 |
| Mike | 29:38 | 9:37 | 4:46 |
| Sarah | 29:46:00 | 29:46:00 | 4:48:00 |
| Roy | 30:31 | 1:30:00 | 4:55:00 |

Gun_time and Net_time: %M:%S where as Pace: %H:%M

How can we ensure that all columns follow HH:MM:SS format?

```
df['Gun_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Gun_time'],format="%H:%M:%S")
```

ValueError: time data '28:48' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: is `29:38` `%H:%M` or `%M:%S`?

Comment: Gun_time and Net_time: %M:%S where as Pace: %H:%M